# Difficulty in undersanding pwd command

Tags: terminal, pwd

I am writing `pwd` in terminal, and it is showing `home/<my_username>`. But I cannot physically find any directory with this path. To clear my confusion, I typed `ls`, but it shows the folders in my Home directory that I can see from file manager. But I cannot a folder with `<my_username>` inside Home. What am I missing here?

```
proteeti@proteeti-X556UQK:~$ pwd
/home/proteeti
proteeti@proteeti-X556UQK:~$ ls
Courses  Dev        Downloads         Music     Public     usr
Desktop  Documents  examples.desktop  Pictures  Templates  Videos
```

No folder named "Proteeti"

Comment: I don't think I have deleted such folder with my name.  I am using ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: the `ls` command will tell you the files inside your current directory, ie `/home/proteeti`. If you want to current dir itself listed, use `ls ..` or `ls /home`.

Comment: `/home` is not your "Home" directory from the file manager. `/home/proteeti` is.

Comment: okay. But are 'home" and "root" directory the same?

Comment: The root directory is the first/top directory in linux if you think of it as a tree it is much easier to understand. Think of a tree where right at the top is the root directory "/" and below that is the main files such as /etc, /home, /boot and so on. Then below these folders are more files and below those files in more files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pwd` will output the pathname of the current directory. When you are located in your home folder, `pwd` will return the pathname of it.

In your case, the pathname of your home folder is `/home/proteeti`.  This is your current working directory.  Typing `ls` whilst located in that folder will show you its contents.

You can not expect to find your home folder *inside* your home folder.

What you could do to see the folder itself is to go up one level in the directory tree, with `cd ..` (or `cd /home`) and do `ls` there.  Your home folder is the one with your username (`proteeti`).   Use `cd proteeti` (or just `cd`) to get back to your home folder.

The directory `/home` is the location where all users' home folders are located.  On a multi-user system, you can expect `/home` to contain all home folders of all users, not only yours.

In Unix parlance, the "root directory" is `/`.  This directory is the top-most directory in the directory tree.  It holds, apart from the `/home` directory, other directories that contain programs and libraries etc., installed by a system administrator. The `/` directory is  not to be confused with `/root`, which is the special home directory of the root (administrator) user.

Related:

- [The Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)
- [Is the slash (/) part of the name of the Linux root directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297969)